# Unable to extract value from XDocument using xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I have a simple xml of users. I have a `StudentId`, I just need to get the student name from the xml on the basis of studentid. Seems to be simple but I am unable to get it done using xpath.

Here's the xml:

```
<Students>
  <Student>
    <StudentId>1</StudentId>
    <StudentName>Mad</StudentName>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <StudentId>2</StudentId>
    <StudentName>Cad</StudentName>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Here's my code:

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/xmlsample.xml"));

string StudentId = "2"; // id to be selected

var username = xmldoc.XPathSelectElement("Students/Student/StudentName").Value;// Not sure how to use where condition here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter by studentId. Should be:

```
var username = xmldoc.XPathSelectElement(String.Format("Students/Student[StudentId={0}]/StudentName", StudentId)).Value;
```